# sync option in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, cache, synchronization

From the `man` pages of `mount` command

> sync   All  I/O  to  the  filesystem should be done synchronously.  In
>   the case of media with a limited number of write cycles (e.g. some
>   flash drives), sync may cause life-cycle shortening.

Does this mean that when providing this option in `/etc/fstab` (given the following definition of `sync` command)

```
$ sync --help
Usage: sync [OPTION] [FILE]...
Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage
```

...caching of contents (i.e. of memory pages created from the contents of the particular device) is prohibited?

Comment: **Don't do that!** This will make your entire system slow. I could even detect by eyes whenever X server read a string inside its binary.

Answer (score 4):

Read caching is not prohibited. Write caching is prohibited. In other words, writes to the device have to be done immediately, so there is no risk of data loss.